# Beaglebone Black strange behaviour during serial connection

Tags: serial-port, environment-variables, beagleboneblack

I installed ubuntuarm on my BBB and lately I wrote a very simple program to test the serial connection.
The program is really trivial, since it echoes all data (that I send from the pc to the board) from the board to the pc.

```
SERIALclass Serial( device, B115200 );

std::string mes = "Sending data through the serial port!";

Serial.writeSerial( mes.c_str() );

while( true ) {

        usleep( 500000 );

        mes = Serial.readSerial();
        Serial.writeSerial( mes.c_str() );
}
```

The configured port is the UART on /dev/ttyO0 and the wires are right connected to the board.

Running the program I get the string, that I expect to see, and then the login mask, which is not wanted. Follows what I see on my pc:

```
Sending data through the serial port!
Password:                                 // <= where is it coming from?!?
```

It seems to me that the /dev/ttyO0 is configured as login port.
My `uEnv.txt` is the following:

```
#Docs: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:U-boot_partitioning_layout_2.0

uname_r=3.14.41-ti-r63
#dtb=
cmdline=coherent_pool=1M quiet

#In the event of edid real failures, uncomment this next line:
#cmdline=coherent_pool=1M quiet video=HDMI-A-1:1024x768@60e

##Example
#cape_disable=capemgr.disable_partno=
optargs=quiet drm.debug=7 cape_enable=capemgr.enable_partno=BB-UART0

##enable BBB: eMMC Flasher:
#cmdline=init=/opt/scripts/tools/eMMC/init-eMMC-flasher-v3.sh

uuid=f5ecbb93-1741-4d46-9c02-8a52110ad7bd
```

How can I get rid off this problem?

I want to use the port to send and receive data and nothing else.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

UART0 is the console and I don't think it can be disabled.  You'll need to send your data on one of the other UARTs.

They'll need enabling via a device tree overlay first.

(old question, but might help someone else)